# Can't insert image into Word doc c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

So, here is my code :

```
doc = app.Documents.Open(fileName, readOnly = false, isVisible = false);
doc.Activate();

string query2 = "SELECT Logo FROM Client WHERE CompanyName = '" + CN + "' ;";
using (SqlCeCommand command1 = new SqlCeCommand(query2, connection))
{
    SqlCeDataReader reader3 = command1.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader3.Read())
    {
        byte[] byteArray = (byte[])reader3["Logo"];
        Image img = byteArrayToImage(byteArray);
        pathImage = @"../../" + CN + "_Logo.JPEG";
        try
        {
            img.Save(pathImage);        
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }            
        doc.Bookmarks["\\EndOfDoc"].Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(pathImage);
    }
}
```

Everything seems good, but i keep getting this random error :

> COMException was unhandled : Invalid file name.

The error happens at the *doc.Bookmarks...* line.
But I have an image at the right folder, and the document works because I use it after in the code. I looked at many topics in many forums and my code don't look wrong. I'm sure there is something very simple to change for it to work.

Please help me!

Thank you

Comment: **warning** your code appears to be vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Interresting! Please explain for me to improve it!

Comment: What kind of value does pathImage contain: could you show us an example that's generic enough so that it doesn't present a security risk? If you hard-code the path to the folder in the code, for testing purposes, does that work or do you get the same error? If you use BACKSLASHES instead of forward slashes do you get a different result? If you record a macro in Word VBA that inserts the picture from this folder and compare how Word records the file path with the file path your code is passing to the method, are they the same? Could there be permissions issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the image path you are getting is not valid path please use break point and check the path.I thing the path should be like this.
 `@"..\" + CN + "_Logo.JPEG"`

Comment: You're right, the path was the issue(which is very weird because it worked to save the image)... To resolve it I changed the path to : _pathImage = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())+"/" + CN + "Logo.jpg";_ It's not exactly where I wanted it to be but hey! too lazy to find a better solution.